# Batch Shutdown Linux Machines from Windows Server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-access, shutdown

I have 20 Ubuntu terminals that run RDP sessions from our RDS server (Server 2012R2).

I want to shut down these machines and night and start them up again in the morning remotely, preferably from the RDS server, but definitely from a Windows-based machine.

For startup, I can us WOL, so there's no issue there.

For shutdown, however, I'm stuck.

What is the best way to automate that shutdown process?

Batch file with Putty script? 
Third-party software? 
Native Batch file with Powershell? 
VNC tools?

I can't imagine this is an issue that hasn't already been dealt with, but I can't seem to find much documentation on it.

EDIT: Facepalming after someone mentioned cron. Definitely a fix for the immediate problem, but I'm still looking for something end-user friendly for the managers of these terminals who are familiar with a GUI interface. I'm thinking of something like Wyse Device Manager (http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/wyse-wdm/pd), but not tailored to that specific brand.

Comment: Why not set a cronjob?  That would be the 'normal' way to have a *nix do something on a schedule.

Comment: I can't even tell you how stupid I feel for not thinking of cron. I got so caught up in higher-level functions/centralized run, etc. That's definitely the temporary fix. However, it would be nice to be do some things on demand, for example restart or shutdown a specific terminal from a server. I don't mind getting into the command line, but the end users who 'supervise' the terminals definitely wouldn't feel comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to initiate commands on your (Ubuntu) Linux machines orchestrated centrally from another host, the tool of choice is usually `ssh`. This is not all that different if your orchestrator host is a Windows machine.

[Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) comes with OpenSSH's version of the client (and the server in the same package, but I certainly would recommend removing the server binaries, especially on a Remote Desktop Server) which can be used to run commands on remote hosts. For automation, you would need some kind of non-interactive authentication - [RSA keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) are a frequently used option due to the low-threshold setup and virtually no dependencies on central authentication infrastructure.

Comment: I'll investigate Cygwin. It's not quite the answer I'm looking for, but it's a helpful pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would use cron for this if you don't need to do this shutdown on demand, but rather according to a schedule. Use "poweroff" in your command line to shut the systems down and power them off.

Is there any harm to letting the systems just run?

Comment: Maybe electricity is expensive in his country?